# Error in chat application in ASP.Net using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, chat

I am developing a web application which has a chat feature. I started developing using SignalR but I got an error while running that particular web page alone.This is the error I am getting.

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource 
required to service this request.Please review the following specific 
parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: 'Virtual_Classroom.chat' is not allowed here 
because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="chat.aspx.cs"       Inherits="Virtual_Classroom.chat" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /chat.aspx    Line: 1
```

Virtual Classroom is the name of my project and chat.aspx is the web page. I compiled and made the chat.aspx page alone to run.The code behind file in chat.aspx is as follows.

```
namespace Virtual_Classroom
{
  [HubName("myChatHub")]
  public partial class chat : Hub
  {
    public void send(string message)
    {
      Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
  }
}
```

In order to make the class derive from the Hub class I removed System.Web.UI.Page and added Hub in the above code. I know that is causing the error.But I don't know how to get rid of that error
 I am new to .Net . Please help.Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Make hub extend from Page. It's the only way that I know of if you still want to extend from Hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy. Your web page `chat.aspx` consists of two parts - the layout (*.aspx) and code behind (*.aspx.cs) which are parts of the same class, and it is **required** that the class in code behind should derive (extend as stated in the question) from `System.Web.UI.Page`. So this change should be reverted, as you've broken your page.

If you want to create a signal r hub for the chat - you should create a separate class for that (in this case it is preferred that this class as well should be in a separate *.cs file) and of course give it another name - I suppose `ChatHub` would be suitable in your case.

Comment: Yes ,I have created a separate class and made the application run.Thanks for spending your time to resolve my error. @danyloid